# Minimizing distance of circles from points without overlapping

Tags: geometry, optimization

I am designing a user interface, and I have encountered the following problem:

I have $p_1 ... p_n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $c_1 ... c_n$ circles with constant $r$ radius. I want to minimize the distance of the $c_i$ circle's center and $p_i$ with the constraint that the circles can not overlap.

Is there a fast algorithm for that? I don't need an exact solution, but a fast one.

Comment: So the $p_i$ are fixed and you want to optimize over the location of the circles' centers?

Comment: Yes, the points are fixed.

Comment: Have you tried formulating the problem as a [SOCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_cone_programming)? I am not sure that it is; just wondering if you've already looked at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem belongs to the family of the circle packing problems. In general is hard to solve to global optimality, but finding a feasible solution might not be that hard.

http://www.packomania.com/

Could you specify more what do you mean for "minimize the distance of the ci circle's center and pi"?

Moreover, I guess It cannot be formulated as SOCP due to the non overlap constraints:

|| c_i - c_j||_2 >= 2r

You can find some SOCP relaxation, not very tight usually.

UPDATE

---

Following the comment the model might be

$min \sum_i || c_i - p_i||^2$

$s.t. || c_i - c_j||_2 >= 2r \quad  \forall i<j$

This is difficult. If you constraints on the region in which the centers can be located, it might even be unfeasible. Otherwise, assuming r is small enough, and you don't really need the global optimum, you might just random generate the centers in a box containing the p_is and run a local search to get a feasible solution.

If you look for some more advanced, I suggest you to google for "circle packing" or "network sensors localization".

Comment: I want the circles to be as close to the fixed points as possible without overlapping.

Comment: ok...something like sum ||c_i - p_i||2 ?

Comment: Yes, exactly...